# Rails - Limited Browsing of User Attachments using ckeditor Gem w/ CanCan & Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, paperclip, cancan

I have everything working correctly, but now I want to limit some user Abilities to perform some attachment actions.

Specifically, the ability to limit the viewing of all uploaded attachments, to those actually uploaded by the User.

Here is the applicable snippet from *ability.rb* I tried ...

```
if user.id
  can :access, :ckeditor
  can [:read, :create, :destroy], Ckeditor::Picture, assetable_id: user.id
  can [:read, :create, :destroy], Ckeditor::AttachmentFile, assetable_id: user.id
end
```

The situation arises when I am using the CKeditor UI, click the *Image* button, and then click the *Browse Server* button to see the previously uploaded images -- right now the image browser shows the uploads of *all* users.  I would like the viewed images to be limited to those of the *current_user* only.

Since the Ckeditor table saves the *assetable_id* of the attachment (i.e. the user.id), and the logic above does not work on its own, I'm guessing some custom Controller logic is also needed here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with custom Ckeditor controllers & some guidance from here:
https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/246

First I needed to make copies of the Ckeditor controllers `pictures_controller.rb` & `attachment_files_controller.rb` and place them here:
`/app/controllers/ckeditor/`

Then a few updates to their suggestions to update `index` were necessary, particularly `picture_model.find_all` needed to be `picture_adapter.find_all` in *pictures_controller.rb* (and similarly `attachment_file_adapter.find_all` in *attachment_files_controller.rb*)

The key to it all is setting the proper scope with: `ckeditor_pictures_scope(assetable_id: ckeditor_current_user)` & `ckeditor_attachment_files_scope(assetable_id: ckeditor_current_user)`

Once these revisions are in place, the file browsers for pictures & attachments show only the appropriate files for that user.

Here are the revised files ... the changes are on line 4 of both.

*/app/controllers/ckeditor/pictures_controller.rb*

```
class Ckeditor::PicturesController < Ckeditor::ApplicationController

  def index
    @pictures = Ckeditor.picture_adapter.find_all(ckeditor_pictures_scope(assetable_id: ckeditor_current_user))
    @pictures = Ckeditor::Paginatable.new(@pictures).page(params[:page])
    respond_with(@pictures, :layout => @pictures.first_page?)
  end

  def create
    @picture = Ckeditor.picture_model.new
    respond_with_asset(@picture)
  end

  def destroy
    @picture.destroy
    respond_with(@picture, :location => pictures_path)
  end

  protected

  def find_asset
    @picture = Ckeditor.picture_adapter.get!(params[:id])
  end

  def authorize_resource
    model = (@picture || Ckeditor.picture_model)
    @authorization_adapter.try(:authorize, params[:action], model)
  end

end
```

*/app/controllers/ckeditor/attachment_files_controller.rb*

```
class Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController < Ckeditor::ApplicationController

  def index
    @attachments = Ckeditor.attachment_file_adapter.find_all(ckeditor_attachment_files_scope(assetable_id: ckeditor_current_user))
    @attachments = Ckeditor::Paginatable.new(@attachments).page(params[:page])
    respond_with(@attachments, :layout => @attachments.first_page?)
  end

  def create
    @attachment = Ckeditor.attachment_file_model.new
    respond_with_asset(@attachment)
  end

  def destroy
    @attachment.destroy
    respond_with(@attachment, :location => attachment_files_path)
  end

  protected

  def find_asset
    @attachment = Ckeditor.attachment_file_adapter.get!(params[:id])
  end

  def authorize_resource
    model = (@attachment || Ckeditor.attachment_file_model)
    @authorization_adapter.try(:authorize, params[:action], model)
  end

end
```

Comment: I think you should add `gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'` to your Gemfile, and add this code to your class `respond_to :html` before `def index`.  Last add this code `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/filebrowser/images/gal_del.png )` to your `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: If you agree with it. I can edit your answer. These are the problems I encountered.

Comment: Thank you a lot! CKeditor was giving me many problems after i set some configurations on config.js file and later, i had this problem with ckeditor controller. Thank you!